# Objects phasing through each other in physics engine

Tags: java, collision-detection, physics, collision-resolution

I'm writing my own physics engine right now ([following this tutorial](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-the-basics-and-impulse-resolution--gamedev-6331)), but I'm running into some problems. Sometimes on collision, objects will just phase through each other instead of bouncing off of each other.

Is there any way I can fix this?

[image]

```
public static void fixCollision(final RectObject a, final RectObject b) {
    final Vec2D normal = collisionNormal(a, b);

    // Calculate relative velocity
    final Vec2D rv = b.velocity.minus(a.velocity);

    // Calculate relative velocity in terms of the normal direction
    final float velAlongNormal = rv.dotProduct(normal);

    // Do not resolve if velocities are separating
    if (velAlongNormal > 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Calculate restitution
    final float e = Math.min(a.restitution, b.restitution);

    // Calculate impulse scalar
    float j = -(1 + e) * velAlongNormal;
    j /= a.getInvMass() + b.getInvMass();

    // Apply impulse
    final Vec2D impulse = normal.multiply(j);
    a.velocity = a.velocity.minus(impulse.multiply(a.getInvMass()));
    b.velocity = b.velocity.plus(impulse.multiply(b.getInvMass()));

    positionalCorrection(a, b);
}

private static void positionalCorrection(final RectObject a, final RectObject b) {

    final Rectangle2D r = new Rectangle2D.Float(a.min.x, a.min.y, a.width(), a.height()).createIntersection(new Rectangle2D.Float(b.min.x, b.min.y,
            b.width(), b.height()));

    final Vec2D normal = collisionNormal(a, b);
    // penetration is the min resolving distance
    final float penetration = (float) Math.min(r.getWidth(), r.getHeight());
    final float percent = 0.01f; // usually .2 to .8
    final float slop = 0.1f; // usually 0.01 to 0.1
    final Vec2D correction = normal.multiply(Math.max(penetration - slop, 0.0f) / (a.getInvMass() + b.getInvMass()) * percent);
    a.min = a.min.minus(correction.multiply(a.getInvMass()));
    a.max = a.max.minus(correction.multiply(a.getInvMass()));

    b.min = b.min.plus(correction.multiply(b.getInvMass()));
    b.max = b.max.plus(correction.multiply(b.getInvMass()));
}

private static Vec2D collisionNormal(final RectObject a, final RectObject b) {
    final float w = 0.5f * (a.width() + b.width());
    final float h = 0.5f * (a.height() + b.height());
    final float dx = a.center().x - b.center().x;
    final float dy = a.center().y - b.center().y;

    if (Math.abs(dx) <= w && Math.abs(dy) <= h) {
        /* collision! */
        final float wy = w * dy;
        final float hx = h * dx;

        if (wy > hx) {
            if (wy > -hx) {
                /* collision at the top */
                return new Vec2D(0, -1);
            } else {
                /* on the left */
                return new Vec2D(-1, 0);
            }
        } else {
            if (wy > -hx) {
                /* on the right */
                return new Vec2D(1, 0);
            } else {
                /* at the bottom */
                return new Vec2D(0, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Rectangles must be colliding");
}
```

RectObject

```
public class RectObject extends GameObject {
    // upper left
    public Vec2D min;
    // bottom right
    public Vec2D max;

    public Vec2D center() {
        return new Vec2D((max.x + min.x) / 2, (max.y + min.y) / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        min = min.plus(velocity);
        max = max.plus(velocity);
    }

    public float width() {
        return max.x - min.x;
    }

    public float height() {
        return max.y - min.y;
    }
}
```

GameObject

```
public abstract class GameObject {
    public static final float INFINITE_MASS = 0;

    private float invMass;
    public Vec2D velocity;
    public float restitution;

    public abstract void update();

    public float getMass() {
        if (invMass == 0) {
            return INFINITE_MASS;
        }
        return 1 / invMass;
    }

    public float getInvMass() {
        return invMass;
    }

    public void setMass(final float mass) {
        if (mass == INFINITE_MASS) {
            invMass = 0;
        } else {
            invMass = 1 / mass;
        }
    }

    public void applyForce(final Vec2D force) {
        velocity = velocity.plus(force.multiply(invMass));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was something wrong with my `collisionNormal` method, where the left and right vectors were actually flipped. This made collisions along the x axis actually push the objects into each other.

```
if (wy > hx) {
    if (wy > -hx) {
        /* collision at the top */
        return new Vec2D(0, -1);
    } else {
        /* on the left */
        return new Vec2D(-1, 0);
    }
} else {
    if (wy > -hx) {
        /* on the right */
        return new Vec2D(1, 0);
    } else {
        /* at the bottom */
        return new Vec2D(0, 1);
    }
}
```

turned into

```
if (wy > hx) {
    if (wy > -hx) {
        /* collision at the top */
        return new Vec2D(0, -1);
    } else {
        /* on the left */
        return new Vec2D(1, 0); // flipped
    }
} else {
    if (wy > -hx) {
        /* on the right */
        return new Vec2D(-1, 0); // flipped
    } else {
        /* at the bottom */
        return new Vec2D(0, 1);
    }
}
```